# writting from text file to id on a website VB.net

Tags: vb.net

im begginner into vb.net and im blocked i want to make my software take text and write int into an ID on website line by line

this is code i use

```
Public Class Form1
    Dim streamer As IO.File
    Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        OpenFileDialog1.ShowDialog()
        TextBox5.Text = OpenFileDialog1.FileName
        Dim R As New IO.StreamReader("C:\" & TheFileName.text & ".txt")
        TheText.Text = R.ReadToEnd
        R.Close()
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button5_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button5.Click
        WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("u_0_1").SetAttribute("value", TextBox5.Text)
    End Sub
End Class
```

the button 5 its the start button and button1 one its upload txt file button
and textbox1 its where the source writed of txt

Comment: What is the problem?

Answer (score 0):

To prevent confusion you should give your controls meaningful names instead of the vb defaults. So TextBox5 should be tbFilename, button1 should be buttReadFile etc.

I've modified your example. Hopefully this works.

```
Public Class Form1

    Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        OpenFileDialog1.ShowDialog()
        Textbox5.Text = OpenFileDialog1.FileName
        TheText.Text = IO.File.ReadAllText(OpenFileDialog1.FileName)
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button5_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button5.Click
        WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("u_0_1").SetAttribute("value", TheText.Text)
    End Sub
End Class
```

`OpenFileDialog1.FileName` should be the full path of the file so we just read it with `Io.File.ReadAllText`. When you write it into the webbrowser you we're using the filename textbox instead of the TheText textbox.

Comment: Thanks Sir but the Buttone1 code i think there is a mistake could you correct it please 
i put it on my vb but it tell me there is an error